# google plus googlecredential java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, google-plus

I'm trying to develop an application in Java with Google Plus. I tried some examples but I didn't have no success.

I have the follow code

```
GoogleCredential cred = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                        .setServiceAccountId("myemail@gmail.com")
                        .setServiceAccountScopes(PlusScopes.all())
                        .build();
```

I'm debugging my app and when pass by .build I have this error

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:362)
at br.com.google.plus.servlet.GoogleCallBack.doGet(GoogleCallBack.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where can I be missing?